# Google App Engine Source Not Updating PHP

Tags: google-app-engine

I cannot get my server code to update. I'm running a PHP instance on GAE and no matter what I do, the files won't update. In the source code view, I can see the files have updated, but when I attempt to access the updated file, I'm still viewing the old version. I've also attempted disconnecting my Bitbucket repo and using the `appcfg.py update project-name` command, but the files aren't refreshing when I attempt to access them. I'm not sure what to do to force the changes to take place.

My app.yaml contains the following code

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always
```

So the files should be getting read, right?

Comment: did you already mark itcas the default version?

Comment: I didn't change the version number in app.yaml (still version: 1). However, when I do change it to version: 2, I still only see Version 1 in my Compute->App Engine->Versions.

Comment: And does appcfg report that it has successfully updated, or does it give any warnings/errors?

Comment: I figured out what went wrong and added it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out what went wrong. I downloaded my code using `appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>` and noticed that I was downloading the old versions of the files (and wasn't downloading the new files). Turns out using source control within GAE will upload new code, but won't deploy it. I attempted to use `appcfg.py update project-name` one more time, but it didn't work. Turns out I didn't disconnect my Bitbucket account (could have sworn that I did...). Once disconnected, I was able to update the project using `appcfg.py update project-name`. While I was figuring this out, I reached out to Google support and received this message:

> To use the feature of push to deploy you need to spin-up the Jenkins
>   Instance on GCE (Google Compute Engine) and then it will take the
>   updated code and execute it in the environment. Go through [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) for how
>   to enable the Jenkins instance and its configuration according to
>   different run time.
>
> In your issue, you just mirrored the code from Bit Bucket to Cloud
>   Repository, as it is just doing the version control for the
>   application not executing the application. So basically you have have
>   the option of using Jenkins instance as I described above to test the
>   different version of the code or using the appcfg.py update command
>   from your local repository.

I haven't attempted to install and use Jenkins since I fixed it after disconnecting my Bitbucket account), but it may help others who have run into this problem.